# stop div after the floating div from wrapping text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have trouble with floats.

see http://jsfiddle.net/hhbjf2wv/4/

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left; width:20px;">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div>

    Just some long long long text Just some long long long textJust some long long long textJust some long long long textJust some long long long text Just some long long long text Just some long long long textJust some long long long textJust some long long long textJust some long long long text

  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to make the description next to the checkbox a proper column (with all the lines indented equally, without wrapping to the leftmost side the first chance they get). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a **margin** and/or **padding** to the div containing the text to align them.

```
.indented_notif_text {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE 1](https://jsfiddle.net/hhbjf2wv/6/)

```
.indented_notif_text {
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/hhbjf2wv/7/)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to add a "height" parameter (if your container has a static content with fixed height) to CSS class:

```
.notif_checkbox 
{
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

or put a margin left (equals to checkbox width) to a text container.

Comment: How can you know the height of the **text**? see this problem => https://jsfiddle.net/hhbjf2wv/8/

Comment: See my "if you now" in description (the content must have a fixed height). Another way is to put a margin left ... to text container. I updated my "if you now" with a more clear description.